# Can gaq.push be used to track events with Google Analytics deployed through Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We want to use Google Tag Manager to deploy our Google Analytics code but we do not want to change over our event tracking _gaq.push('_trackEvent') over to the Google Tag Manager dataLayer method yet.

Is this something that is possible or do we need to migrate those events to Google Tag Manager at the same time?

From posts to the Google Forums it look like this is not recommended.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tag-manager/_gaq.push$20with$20google$20tag$20manager/tag-manager/9jSsmZhzuCo/vOAwcQqba0QJ
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/cglXIlLmTvc

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is possible but I'm not certain. You could set it up on the fly and test it out in debug mode:

1. Add your base tag (Google Analytics page view tag) to all pages.
2. Select Preview > Debug and then visit the website in question
3. Open the console and check using your go to debugging tool. I use GA Debugger for chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en)
4. Try clicking a link or button that triggers an event using __gaq.push

Comment: Thanks for the resource. None of my event tracking is being logged when using GA gaq.push and Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager.